# The `*` in `sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)`

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the official doc of [2. Built-in Functions — Python 3.6.5](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted)

> sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False):
>
> Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.
> Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword arguments.

The docs do not mention the `*`, what's it's function here?

There exist not such a symbol `*` in the previous version as `sorted(iterable[, key][, reverse])`